# aframe vector unproject not working and not sure?bug?

Tags: three.js, aframe

I try used threejs to test out simple 3D plane without mesh object just zero plane base on camera with unproject and it work. But I try on Aframe it didn't work and there is bug.

getInverse > m.elements error that it show on the console log.

Here simple example of Aframe. https://gist.github.com/Lightnet/8fb3d4a7c5f3ed2b3865bf894aecb9b8

Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't perform your operations on the `camera = document.querySelector('[camera]');`, because it grabs the a-frame's wrapper around the three camera.

You can access the three camera with `camera.components.camera.camera`.
As noted, You can also grab it by the reference `AFRAME.scenes[0].camera`.

Check it out on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/by7f2334/).

Comment: Oh didn't know. I tired but didn't work for some reason. The position is zero for some reason. 
--edit--
Manage to get it working but I need to try to figure out which way it somewhat buggy. I am not sure how camera position work and I found the position is zero. Just need help on y=zero.

https://jsfiddle.net/by7f2334/2/

Comment: `camera.components.camera.camera`?

Comment: @pailhead the `camera` variable is his reference to the entity. So to access the camera component, you need to do `camera.components.camera`. The three.js camera within the component is stored in `camera` so finally you get `camera.components.camera.camera`

Comment: Also accessible via the scene: `AFRAME.scenes[0].camera`.

Comment: @ngokevin thanks, i've totally forgot about it, looks neater so i've added it to the anwser :)