# aframe mouseup on sphere

Tags: three.js, aframe

following a partly sucessful answer to this question [AFRAME position far away from camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48453818/aframe-position-far-away-from-camera/48457395#48457395)

I'm trying to use a sphere around the camera to get a position around 100 from the camera.

I've added this sphere

```
    <Entity
      id='mouse-listener'
      geometry='primitive: sphere;
                  radius: 100;
                  segmentsWidth: 64;
                  segmentsHeight: 64;'
      position='0 0 0'
      scale="-1 1 1"
      material={{color: 'blue' }}
      className='clickable'
      events={{click: (e) => console.log(e)}}
    />
```

And my camera is as such

```
  <Entity primitive='a-camera' id='camera' look-controls={`enabled:${isLookControlsEnabled}`} mouse-cursor mouse-zoom wasd-controls={wasdControls}>
```

I've tried adding the example listener component to the sphere entity

```
import AFRAME from 'aframe'

AFRAME.registerComponent('cursor-listener', {
  init: function () {
    this.el.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
      console.log('I was clicked at: ', evt.detail.intersection.point)
    })
  },
})
```

I just want to know the point on which it was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

A-Frame comes with a mouse [cursor](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/cursor.html). You add it as a separate entity:

```
<a-entity cursor="rayOrigin: mouse"></a-entity>
```

The events are `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`, `click`, `mousedown`, `mouseup`. Not `onmouseup`.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, does the event from this entity include the point where it hits? I'd included the Mouse Cursor component, I thought this might do it.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I've been following this but the intersection in detail is always null. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: Also get this error 'aframe-mouse-cursor-component.js:494 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'matrixWorld' of undefined
    at NewComponent._updateIntersectObject'  when I add this to the entity           mouse-cursor
          events={{click: (e) => console.log(e)}}