# Get position of upper left corner of field of view

Tags: aframe

I want to be able to place an entity in the upper left corner of the view port. It is easy to hardcode the positioning, but of course this breaks for different screen sizes. Is there a way to get the xy coordinated of the upper left corner of the what is visible in the camera. I.e. what is the x distance from the center of the screen to the edge and what is the y distance from the center to the top?

Comment: take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48434953/aframe-screen-to-world-position

Comment: @ThomasWilliams Wow thank you! That is super helpful. Im getting close. If i log the camera's bounding rect, the position is off the screen. Why would the camera's rect not be in the visible field of view?

Comment: getBoundingClientRect returns a screen space 2D vector. The next few lines convert the mouse pos (within the rect) to 3D space. You can use that to place your object in 3D. Instead of using the mouse position, feed in a 2D vector of where in screen space you want your object to live. Hope that makes sense. I haven't tested any of this in the real world.

Comment: If you figured out how to make this work, would you mind posting a simple glitch demo so future users can learn from you?

Comment: I will for sure if/when i get it. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, which allows you to fix an aframe element in the camera's view based on screen coordinates.

```
const visibleHeightAtZDepth = ( depth ) => {
  const camera = AFRAME.scenes[0].camera;
  // compensate for cameras not positioned at z=0
  const cameraOffset = camera.position.z;
  if ( depth < cameraOffset ) depth -= cameraOffset;
  else depth += cameraOffset;

  // vertical fov in radians
  const vFOV = camera.fov * Math.PI / 180; 

  // Math.abs to ensure the result is always positive
  return 2 * Math.tan( vFOV / 2 ) * Math.abs( depth );
};

const visibleWidthAtZDepth = ( depth ) => {
  const camera = AFRAME.scenes[0].camera;
  const height = visibleHeightAtZDepth( depth, camera );
  let width = height * camera.aspect;
  return width;
};

const setHudPosition = ( fovWidth, fovHeight, depth) => {
  document.getElementById('hud').object3D.position.set(-fovWidth/2, fovHeight/2, depth);
}

setHudPosition(visibleWidthAtZDepth(-1), visibleHeightAtZDepth(-1), -1);
```

You can use the height and width functions to get the visible field of view at arbitrary depths.